# How to fix issue "There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree" in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a newbie in Flutter and try to make wallpaper applications. Firstly, my app is working fine without any errors. When I try to implement pagination when scrolling. I got an error

There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree

I understand the Hero tag needs a unique key. I tried to add a unique key in the hero tag but looks like some code loaded a duplicate hero tag in view. sometimes look like it repeats to load all item instead because I have some image starting to load again.

My example code

```
void _scrollListerner() async {
    if (isLoadingMore) return;
    if (scrollController.position.pixels ==
        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      setState(() {
        isLoadingMore = true;
      });
      page += 1;
      await fetchData();
      setState(() {
        isLoadingMore = false;
      });
    }

    print(page);
  }
}
```

Update for FectData code

```
 Future<void> fetchData() async {
    print("fetchData");
    final url = 'https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated?per_page=15&page=$page';
    final headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': apiKey,
    };
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        photos += jsonData['photos'];
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }
```

how to prevent it from loading twice time or loading all?

Comment: share fetchData() method!

Comment: If your response has the id or any unique key, try setting it as a hero tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used FloatingActionButton in your page,add null as herogtag in that will fix your issue

```
FloatingActionButton(
  heroTag: null,
  ...
)
```

Or Else you have Hero widget in your code you can assign a unique tag for like this

```
Hero(tag: UniqueKey(),child:Container())
```

Comment: I try to assign but it does not work because it fetch data multiple times when scrolling. I have no idea to prevent it load duplicate heroTag